# Flex Specification yytext

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I'm trying to build a flex specification for the `k` notation, for instance: `3k5 = 3500`.
I have the following:

```
[0-9]+{LETTER}      { yyless(yyleng-1); yy_push_state(X_REAL); aux = atof(yytext); }
<X_REAL>"k"[0-9]+   { yytext[0] = "." ; printf("%f", ((atof(yytext) * 10^(3)) + aux * 10^(3))); }
```

However I get an error when trying to put `"."` in the first char of yytext:

> In member function ‘virtual int AtScanner::yylex()’:
>   error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
>   error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator^’

How can I manipulate the yytext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot modify `yytext`, it's `const`.

You should go another way: perhaps just allocate a new string using [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html)?

Other problem: `yytext[0]` is a `char`, so should be the rhs. So we need `'.'` instead of `"."`.

Yet another problem: `10^3` is not producing 1000, in C it's bitwise exclusive OR operator (thanks to @Chris for pointing this out). So just put plain 1000 instead.

So, the final code should look like:

```
<X_REAL>"k"[0-9]+   { char* number = strdup(yytext);
                      number[0] = '.';
                      printf("%f", ((atof(number) * 1000) + aux * 1000));
                      free(number); }
```

Note that I didn't check the correctness of calculations.

---

Per @rici's comment, modifying `yytext` should be ok, so the code can be simplified as follows:

```
<X_REAL>"k"[0-9]+   { yytext[0] = '.';
                      printf("%f", ((atof(yytext) * 1000) + aux * 1000)); }
```

Comment: I just want to substitute the letter with a dot. I tried this now :<X_REAL>"k"[0-9]+  { std::string num = new std::string(yytext) ; num[0] = "."; 
printf("%f", ((atof(yytext) * 10^(3)) + aux * 10^(3))); 

and it gives me:

error: conversion from ‘std::string*’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string’ requested
 error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘op

Comment: @pirezas: Than you have to allocate a new string and parse it: `char* copy_of_yytext = strdup(yytext); copy_of_yytext[0] = ...; ... free(copy_of_yytext);`

Comment: I tried your way and it still gives me the error from converting from const char* to char

Comment: `std::string num = new std::string(yytext);` is wrong. Use just `std::string num(yytext);` or `strdup`.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Could you please post the updated code and the error message?

Comment: `<X_REAL>"k"[0-9]+  { char* num = strdup(yytext); num[0] = "."; printf("%f", ((atof(yytext) * 10^(3)) + aux * 10^(3))); }`


error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’
error: invalid operands of types ‘double’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator^’

Comment: First of all, you need to pass `num` to atof. Second, I don't see in your code any conversion to **char**, so the mistake must be somewhere else.

Comment: And of course C has no operator `^`, so please just put `1000` instead of `10^3`. (This might be the real error now.)

Comment: Hmm the mistake is in this line and column "char* num = strdup(ytext);"

I don't know why though...

Comment: Yes that solved the other error but the conversion to char error is still ocurring

Comment: Silly me: replace `"."` with `'.'`!

Comment: Actually there IS an operator ^, but its xor not pow, so 10^3 == 9, which is not at all what you want...

Comment: @Chris: well, you're right, but in that context easier was to say there isn't. Anyway, there isn't `^` for double and int (since `aux * 10^(3)` is interpreted as `(aux * 10)^3` actually (and I am not sure about the `+`'s priority)).

Comment: I know this comment is seven years too late but I just stumbled upon this answer. `yytext` is not `const` and the flex-scanner doesn't care about its contents so you are totally free to modify them. Just keep your hands off the buffer beyond the token itself.

Comment: @rici: Oh, indeed? I didn't know and defensively tried to avoid manipulating the memory I don't own. Do you know any documentation speaking about it?

Comment: The (non-)limitation on the modification of `yytext` comes straight out of the [flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Actions.html#index-yytext_002c-modification-of). Modifying `yytext` is a venerable technique; see the third example in the original 1975 paper by Lesk&Schmidt ([reproduced here](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/lex/index.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Modifying yytext (or a copy) seems like a bad way of going about this.  Why not just extract the numbers directly?

```
[0-9]+k[0-9]+    { char *p;
                   long first = strtol(yytext, &p, 10);
                   long second = strtol(p+1, 0, 10);
                   double value = first*1000.0 + second*pow(10.0, p-yytext-yyleng+4.0);
                   printf("%f", value); }
```

Comment: `pow` is quite slow, multiplying/dividing by 10 several times would be faster.